# Finding a MAX value based on multiple criteria Excel

Tags: excel, max

I have created a downloadable sheet in GoogleDrive to show my problem.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O8fnWQyTFcsqfHAsmpiY4o-n2_xbC-yue2QI4Ww4kSI/edit?usp=sharing

I need to combine the following formula which finds the maximum value in H1:H1024 which is less than or equal to the value specified in B16

```
    {=MAX(IF(H1:H1024<=B16,H1:H1024, 0))}
```

with a formula which adds the argument that the cell adjacent to the value must contain all the elements listed a range of cells D1:D10 - the following formula returns TRUE when that is the case

```
    =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$1:$D$10,F1)))=COUNTA($D$1:$D$10)
```

The following does not work but illustrates what I am trying to achieve

```
    {=MAX(IF(AND(H1:H1023<=B16,E1:E1023="TRUE"),H1:H1023, 0))}
```

where E1 contains the SUMPRODUCT formula dragged down to E1023.

In know a macro would be better for this (and would make dealing more items viable) but that is not an option for me.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=MAX(IF(H1:H1023<=B16,IF(E1:E1023,H1:H1023)))
```

It is an array formula so Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Array formulas do not like the AND/OR functions.  One must chain IF functions for each desired check.

The false option is not needed when using the IF statements this way.

Comment: I am impressed by your facility with array formulas.

Comment: Thanks the array IF structure works as you said,but the formula you gave does not as the TRUE/FALSE is cannot be used as at text value. However if I putting a "--" (double unary) in forces formula to return 0 for FALSE and 1 for TRUE and this can be used as per my answer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction-  I was completely stuck

Comment: @SteelyDanFan see edit.  the `= "TRUE" is not needed.

Comment: Even better! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

@ScottCraner got there before me but you can also put "--" in front of a reference to the TRUE/FALSE column to force it to a numeric value (1 for TRUE, 0 for FALSE) like this

```
    =MAX(IF(H1:H1023<=B16,IF(--E1:E1023=1,H1:H1023)))
```

but as @ScottCraner points out, you can just leave the range as is so his answer should prevail as is less complex.